# Force enabling TRIM before setup assistant is run

Tags: macos, command-line, ssd, setup-assistant

Basically, I'm preparing to give a MacBook Pro, running Mac OS X 10.11.4, to someone, but I need to execute "sudo trimforce enable" beforehand, as it contains an aftermarket SSD (fully compatible with TRIM). I wanted them to be able to use the normal setup assistant, so creating a user to run the command is not ideal.

Is it possible to boot into recovery or single user mode and run the command, without having to create a user account?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can boot into OS X Recovery mode by pressing CMD+R at startup, after it boots and OS X Utility comes up, go to Application menu and them Terminal. Then you can execute `sudo trimforce enable`. You can also boot into single user mode and execute the command (If it doesn't work in single user mode them try taking out the sudo).

Comment: OS X Recovery does not save anything permanently to disk so it won't survive the next reboot.